# Concise/elegant integration using pandas Series elements as bounds

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas dataframe, which I'll call df. It has columns 'A' and 'B'.

```
    A   B
1   0   3
2   1   4
3   2   5
```

I want to add a column, 'C'. 'C' should be the definite integral of a function f on the bounds ('A', 'B'). At the moment, the function f is just f(x) = x, but in the future I will have different functions that'll need mapping in, so rather than trivially solving the integral and calculating 'C' as (B^2 - A^2)/2, I'd like to implement a programmatic solution.

The following works:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad

df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: quad(lambda x: x, x[0], x[1])[0], axis=1)
```

However, it also seems really inelegant. I find it hard to believe that a dataframe method applying a lambda function that contains another function which takes a third function (also, for the moment, a lambda) as input is *really* the best way to do this.

Is there a less syntactically terrible way to achieve my end goal of defining 'C' as the integral of f on the bounds ('A', 'B')?

Comment: I think your solution is simple enough, but if the DataFrame is large it will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your approach is fine, but I would recommend something like the following to improve readability:

```
# Explicitly define your function.
def func(x):
    # For example, y = x^2
    return x ** 2

# Explicitly reference A and B end points.
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda x: quad(func, x.A, x.B)[0], axis=1)
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
df['C'] = [quad(func, a, b)[0] for a, b in zip(df.A, df.B)]
```

Comment: +1 for list comprehension. Minor note: PEP8 says to always use def instead of assigning a lambda function. Depending on your style guidelines, it might be more appropriate to write `def func(x): return x**2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and easy to understand pandas series integration routine that does not rely on the scipy.quad routine.

```
def intSeries(ser):
        """
        Integrates the pandas series ser
        returns the tine series of the integral of ser with the same index
        """
        time = ser.index
        ints = [0]
        for n in range(1,len(time)):
            dt = time[n] - time[n - 1]
            rt = .5 * (series[time[n]] + series[time[n - 1]]) * dt
            ints.append(ints[n - 1] + rt)
        intf = pd.Ser(index=time, data=ints)
        return intf
```